# Split a file in windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-management

I have a VBK file, which is sitting around 3.4TB

I want to split it into two volumes at 1.7TB

I have tried a few different options including UnxUtils, which worked perfectly for small files but as soon as I try to split larger files it fails with an error "invalid number of bytes" when I reduce the bytes to 1.9GB it provides the error "Memory exhausted"

Due to this, it feels as though the UnxUtil is not suitable for what I'm after, I also tried HJSplit but this hasn't worked either, anyone know any way to split this large file into two smaller files?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: There are tons of other tools. What did you try and what error did they give? Did you trụ command line?